# Eclipse product export wizard showing "the product's defining plugin could not be found"

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am creating application using Eclipse Product Export Wizard. I have tick the "Synchronize before exporting" "the product's defining plugin could not be found". If I untick the "Synchronize before exporting" it gives me run time error.

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.equinox.ds [60]
Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.felix.scr; bundle-version="[2.0.0,3.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"

```
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1682)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1662)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1624)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1555)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

...

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-03-03 13:37:35.323
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "**XYZ**" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.equinox.app.error.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1498)
```

Comment: Sounds like your list of plug-ins / features is out of date. org.eclipse.equinox.ds was replaced with org.apache.felix.scr some time ago. Note that the product export wizard is now deprecated - [tag:tycho] with [tag:maven] is the only supported way to build a RCP.